# cross-referencing a list item in OPmac

Tags: cross-referencing, plain-tex, opmac

I need to give a reference to a list item in plain TeX. I have a numbered list with a custom style.

```
\begitems \sdef{item:F}{\bf FP\the\itemnum\kern.25em} \style F
    * List item 1
    * List item 2
    * List item 3
\enditems
```

The list gives out the following result:

```
FP1 List item 1
FP2 List item 2
FP3 List item 3
```

where FPx is the bullet.

I want to reference the indidividual list items so that the FPx shows up in the referencing text, such as:

```
As seen in the bullet FPx.
```

How would I go on with that? I've seen something similar is possible to do [in Latex](http://texblog.org/2012/03/21/cross-referencing-list-items/), but I have no clue how to approach it in plain TeX.

I have tried to add a \label to the bullet, but \ref will render only as a reference to the \secc above it.

Comment: Are you using OPmac?

Comment: Yes, i am using OPmac.

Comment: Then read last sentence of part 3 of the user manual for OPmac, you should find the answer there

Comment: Thank you very much. I see what I'm missing. I have edited the question to better express what I need and cannot find even in the OPmac manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
\input opmac

\begitems \sdef{item:F}{\bf FP\the\itemnum\kern.25em \wlabel{\bf FP\the\itemnum\kern.25em}} \style F

  * List item 1
\label[item]
  * List item 2
  * List item 3

\enditems


I'm referring to \ref[item].

\bye
```

Comment: You're the best, this works perfectly. And I learned a little bit more of TeX in the process. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy you find this useful :)